# JavaScript-Dot navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How can I code the Javascript or jQuery so that when I click on a dot the dot gets an active class but the previous dots class is removed?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dotnav">
    <div class="dot active" title="Sign Up"></div>
    <div class="dot" title="hello"></div>
    <div class="dot" title="hello"></div>
    <div class="dot" title="hello"></div>
    <div class="dot" title="hello"></div>
    <div class="dot" title="helloup"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dotnav {
    left: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: block;
    /*-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50);*/
}

.dot {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align;
    baseline;
}

.dot:hover {
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    background-color: #C9931E;
}

.active {
    background-color: #C9931E;
}
```

How can I code the Javascript or jQuery so that when I click on a dot, the dot gets an active class, but the previous dots class is removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.dot').on('click', function() {
    $('.dot.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it this way:

```
$('.dot').click(function(){
    this.className = 'active';
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qtgye/q5p6fj5y/)

Answer (score 0):

On click, remove the active class then add `active` on the clicked dot. Something like this:

```
$('.dot').click(function () {
    $('div.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/L95d7hy6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use on(), not click(); It's easier to read when in complex code, and you can namespace your event.
// ALWAYS namespace your events
// It's also a good idea to pass your event to your anonymous function - saves lots of time if your patterns are the same
$('.dot').on('click.dot', function(e){
  // Remove 'active' class from all siblings in a single line
  // We remove from siblings so that other 'dot' structures can be used without being interfered with
  // If you want multiple set to sync their behaviour - write in data-attr and sync up that way (new question if you want to give that a go)
  $(this).siblings('.dot').removeClass('active');
  // Then, apply to the current clicked on element
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

jFiddle with your original HTML and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/q5p6fj5y/1/